# How do you repair a hole in a concrete floor in a second story bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, concrete, floor

The plumber chiseled a hole in a concrete floor in a second story bathroom floor to install a toilet. How do you replace the concrete he removed so the toilet has a solid support and stops rocking?

Comment: If you can show us a picture of what's left, we can better help. Why didn't the plumber fix his mess?

Comment: Obligatory song cue: "The Gasman Cometh"  (Flanders and Swann, I think). https://youtu.be/mOA_SUKEZRE?si=pTire12sPVyFy1qW